# GoogleMobileAds.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I know that there must be a whole bunch of questions like this, but I tried everything, and nothing would work.

I'm creating a iOS app, and I use Google Ad Mob. I built my Xcode project from Unity, but when I tried to archive it in Xcode, there is this annoying error "GoogleMobileAds.h file not found"! I have the Google Mobile Ad Framework, but when I put it in the project, the error still shows! I looked up this problem, and tried to follow some of the people to fixed it, but the error still wouldn't go away.

Could anyone help please?

Here is the link to the project you can download.

[Xcode project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L5BFEWOigiXwoDhmKdlFmn-lrHDLcPdH)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by going to Framework Search Paths in build settings, and putting in the GoogleMobileAd.framework!

Answer (score 1):

as @SullyBully already correctly mentioned.

You have to add your folder with the Admob SDK to Framework Search Paths in Build Settings.

Additionally you have to include your GoogleMobildeAds.framework into your frameworks section in xcode (no ideas whats that called)

See screenshot 1 and 2 (I literally spent now hours because of it, hopefully this finds a soul helpful :P)

[image]

[image]

By the way it is completely neccessary just to include GoogleMobildeAds.framework.
You dont need to include the others like GoogleUtilities, or GoogleAppMeasurement etc.

Answer (score 0):

After you build the the game in Unity.You also have to add google admob iOS library to your Xcode project. You can get from : [https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download][1]

Comment: I did. I imported the GoogleMobileAds.framework, GoogleUtilities.framework, and the other ones, and put them into the folder where the xcode project is. Is there any way that I can put the xcode project so you can see?